# How to use for loop in when condition using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to check multiple column values in when and otherwise condition if they are `0` or not. We have spark dataframe having columns from 1 to 11 and need to check their values. Currently my code looks like this:-

```
df3 =df3.withColumn('Status', when((col("1") ==0)|(col("2") ==0)|(col("3") ==0)| (col("4") ==0) |(col("5") ==0)|(col("6") ==0)|(col("7") ==0)| (col("8") ==0)|(col("9") ==0)|(col("10") ==0)| (col("11") ==0) ,'Incomplete').otherwise('Complete'))
```

How can I achieve this by just using for loop instead of so many `or` conditions

Comment: are you columns really named with number only ? That's a terrible naming. 
With proper naming (at least `c1`, `c2`, etc...) you could simply use `F.expr` to get your result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the code below to collect you conditions and join them into a single string, then call `eval`.

Code

```
cond ='|'.join('(col("'+str(_)+'")==0)' for _ in range(1, 12))

cond = '('+cond+')'

print(cond)

#((col("1")==0)|(col("2")==0)|(col("3")==0)|(col("4")==0)|(col("5")==0)|(col("6")==0)|(col("7")==0)|(col("8")==0)|(col("9")==0)|(col("10")==0)|(col("11")==0))

df3 = df3.withColumn('Status', when(eval(cond),'Incomplete').otherwise('Complete'))
```

Comment: @Amol You are welcome. You can study the other better solutions too if you wish.

Answer (score 10):

I propose a more *pythonic* solution. Use `functools.reduce` and `operator.or_`.

```
import operator
import functools

colnames = [str(i+1) for i in range(11)]
df1 = spark._sc.parallelize([
  [it for it in range(11)], 
  [it for it in range(1,12)]]
).toDF((colnames))

df1.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

cond_expr = functools.reduce(operator.or_, [(f.col(c) == 0) for c in df1.columns])

df1.withColumn('test', f.when(cond_expr, f.lit('Incomplete')).otherwise('Complete')).show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11|      test|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|Incomplete|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11|  Complete|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------+
```

This way you don't need to define any functions, evaluate string expressions or use python lambdas. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a better solution

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,0,0,2),(1,1,1,1)],['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  0|  2|
|  1|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+

def status(x):
  l = [i for i in x]
  if 0 in l:
    return 'Incomplete'
  else:
    return 'Complete'

>>> df.rdd.map(lambda x:  (x.c1, x.c2, x.c3, x.c4,status(x))).toDF(['c1','c2','c3','c4','status']).show()
+---+---+---+---+----------+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|    status|
+---+---+---+---+----------+
|  1|  0|  0|  2|Incomplete|
|  1|  1|  1|  1|  Complete|
+---+---+---+---+----------+
```

Comment: While this will work in a small example, this doesn't really scale, because the combination of `rdd.map` and `lambda` will force the Spark Driver to call back to python for the `status()` function and losing the benefit of parallelisation.